# How do I do mutations? Application is being blocked because of JWT tokens is protecting the route

Tags: graphql

I'm to new GraphQL and I'm wondering how I can stay logged in when I want to do mutations as a logged in user in the GraphQL playground. How would I stayed logged in?

```js
const getLoggedInUser = async req => {
  const token = req.headers["x-token"];
  if (token) {
    try {
      return await jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new AuthenticationError(AUTHORISATION_MESSAGES.SESSION_EXPIRED);
    }
  }
  return token;
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your code, you should pass the token in HTTP header like this

```js
{
    “x-token”: “<put ur token here>”
}
```